# Does transforming keyrunes count towards Evolve?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Suppose I animate my [Simic Keyrune](http://gatherer.wizards.com/pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=366357) into a 2/3 artifact creature. Will it evolve my 1/1 [Fathom Mage](http://gatherer.wizards.com/pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=366399)?

Comment: "Transform" has a specific meaning in magic, and it doesn't apply here. The word "animate" is usually used. Fixed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [If a land becomes a creature, has it entered the battlefield?](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/11009/if-a-land-becomes-a-creature-has-it-entered-the-battlefield)

Comment: (The duplicate is about lands turning into creatures, but I think it's pretty clear the answer wouldn't be different for an artifact.)

Comment: Despite having the same answer, the two are distinct questions. More info: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57836/147335

Comment: @corsiKa, It's only a different question if you don't realize it doesn't matter whether the card being animated was an artifact or land. I don't think anyone would fail to realize that, including the OP. Way too many questions are marked as "duplicate" when they shouldn't be, but I think you're just being too nitpicky here.

Comment: @ikegami People's perception of a question do not change the actual properties of those questions. "It's only a different question if" means "It's a different question" and, ergo, not a duplicate. You cannot rely on knowing the answer to categorize the question. This is a fundamental tenet of the Stack Exchange philosophy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, Evolve triggers on creatures entering the battlefield, and the Keyrune must necessarily be on the the battlefield to use its ability.

Changing an object's characteristics (power, toughenss, type, etc) does not cause it to enter or leave the battlefield.

---

> 702.99a Evolve is a triggered ability. “Evolve” means “Whenever a creature enters the battlefield under your control, if that creature’s power is greater than this creature’s power and/or that creature’s toughness is greater than this creature’s toughness, put a +1/+1 counter on this creature.”

Comment: And What about Zameck Guildmage? If i use its ability to make my new creature enter the battlefield with a +1/+1 counter on it then if I cast another Fathom Mage will it evolve my 1/1 one?

Comment: Zameck Guildmage causes creatures to enter with the +1/+1 counter -- there is never a moment it's on the battlefield without the +1/+1 counter -- so Evolve does see the higher modified P/T from the +1/+1 counter as you would want. It won't add a counter to a Keyrune being animated, though.

Comment: I've added a sentence to my last comment.