# Landfall, land creature enter effect

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I have a creature like [Embodiment of Fury](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bEmbodiment%20of%20Fury%5d) and I play a land and use its landfall effect on the land that just entered will it trigger entry effects, for example [Elemental Bond](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bElemental%20Bond%5d)?

Is it seen as entering as a land then turning into a creature or is it seen as entering as a creature?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If a permanent transforms into a creature, has it entered the battlefield?](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/11009/if-a-permanent-transforms-into-a-creature-has-it-entered-the-battlefield)

Comment: I'm retracting my close vote - this question is about the grayer-seeming area of a triggered ability that "immediately" turns the land into a creature. The answer is ultimately the same (no, it wasn't a creature when it entered), but it's worth discussing how triggered abilities are not instantaneous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The land enters as a land, and only later turns into a creature. This is because Embodiment of Fury's effect is a triggered ability, so the ability has to go on the stack after the land enters, and only later when the ability resolves (perhaps much later, if the players feel like responding to it) does the land become a creature. If instead you controlled e.g. a *static* ability which said something like "All lands are also 3/3 creatures", the land would enter as a creature and trigger effects like Elemental Bond.

Comment: thanks, BTW not a magic related question but how did you make the links on the cards i mentioned

Comment: That was actually the previous editor @murgatroid99. You do it like this: "[mtg:Embodiment of Fury]", and then [magical behind the scenes stuff](http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/726/please-add-support-for-the-magic-autocard-window/771#771) turns it into a Gatherer link. (And for future reference, if you ever want to see the markdown that created a post, just click the edit button.)